# Swagger, как в интерфейсе поместить свойства объекта в отдельные поля?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Возможно ли в Swagger в интерфейсе поместить свойства объекта в отдельные поля, как указано на скриншоте ниже? Версия Swagger 2.0 или 3.0.

Вот пример того, как нужно сделать:

[image: Нужно поместить свойства таким образом]

У меня получается только такой вариант (код для версии 3.0):

Код requestBody:

```
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                example_obj:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    field1:
                      type: string
                    from:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        field2:
                          type: string
                    field3:
                      type: string
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

UPDATE:
Скриншот с более подробным описанием вопроса.

[image: UPDATE]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: картинка "результат" как-бы говорит, что request body у вас подходит под требование "поместить свойства объекта в отдельные поля". совсем не понятно в чём ваше затруднение.

Comment: @nörbörnën Сейчас у меня все свойства объекта "example_obj" находятся в одном поле ввода, которое не очень удобно редактировать (скриншот "Результат").
Я же хочу узнать, возможно ли для каждого свойства объекта "example_obj" сделать отдельное поле ввода (как на скриншоте с примером)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Components](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/) служат контейнером для различных многократно используемых определений - схем (моделей данных), параметров, ответов, примеров и других

```
paths:
  /xyz:
    post:
      tags:
        - Example
      summary: Example summary
      parameters:
      - in: header
        name: host
        description: Хост
        required: false
        schema:
          type: string
      requestBody:
        description: Example requestBody description
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/businessAddressRequest'
      responses:
        '201':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/littlePony'

components:
  schemas:
    businessAddressRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        uuid:
          type: string
          title: Uuid
        field:
          type: string
          title: Field title
      required:
        - field

    littlePony:
      type: object
      properties:
        uuid:
          type: string
          title: Uuid
        name:
          type: string
          title: lalala
      required:
        - name
```

Comment: Там тоже у свойств объекта не то оформление, которое мне нужно. Видимо, я не совсем корректно выразился в вопросе. Добавил для вас скриншот с описанием моей проблемы в моем первом сообщении.

Comment: @mkv для requestBody так не сделать. в секции [parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/) можно прописать только параметры path parameters, query parameters, header parameters, cookie parameters.